# Changing the type of a symbol

Tags: relation-symbols

Consider the output of `texdef -t latex \flat`

> ```
> \flat:
> \mathchar"15B
>
> \the\flat:
> 347
> ```

I'd like to save the `\flat` command and then redefine it to work as binary symbol, for example, the same space around as `\times`.

I'm using this

```
\let\oldflat\flat 
\renewcommand{\flat}{\mathbin\oldflat}
\[ a\oldflat b \neq a\flat b \]
```

but I'd like to confirm here if this is the right way to to this.

Comment: looks good to me.  i'd probably wrap braces around `\oldflat` in the redefinition, but i think it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: ...unless you want the size to change in `\displaystyle`, or if you want it to accept limits. `:^)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the symbol is ordinary, then

```
\mathchardef\oflat=\flat
\mathchardef\flat=\numexpr"2000+\oflat\relax
```

will do, because 2 is the class number for binary operation symbols. The trick is that a `\mathchardef` token can be used in the context of a `<number>`. It's necessary to first get an equivalent because when the number for `\mathchardef\flat` is being evaluated, `\flat` is temporary set equal to `\relax`, to avoid some problems that could arise from sloppy input.

```
\documentclass{article}

\mathchardef\oflat=\flat
\mathchardef\flat=\numexpr"2000+\oflat\relax

\begin{document}

\[ a\oflat b \neq a\flat b \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I can not appreciate your elegant solution because my pour knowledge... lol but I'm sure that it is sophisticated. Do you have an example showing some possible difference between your solution compared with mine?

Comment: @Sigur Try `A_\flat` with your code and with mine. `;-)`

Comment: Mine is problematic. I got `Missing { inserted. \[ A_\flat`. Thanks.